# method put python unauthorized 401

Tags: python, put, unauthorized

i have a python script , i will send an image to server, so i use "put" method , 
the server respond : 401 unauthorized

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_EnvoiPhotos (__main__.EnvoiPhotos)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/funkload/FunkLoadTestCase.py", line 946, in __call__
    testMethod()
  File "test_EnvoiPhotos.py", line 74, in test_EnvoiPhotos
    self.put(self.server_url + "/contacts/41.json",Data('application/json',data),description = "put photo")
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/funkload/FunkLoadTestCase.py", line 408, in put
    load_auto_links=load_auto_links)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/funkload/FunkLoadTestCase.py", line 401, in method
    method=method, load_auto_links=load_auto_links)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/funkload/FunkLoadTestCase.py", line 299, in _browse
    response = self._connect(url, params, ok_codes, method, description)
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/funkload/FunkLoadTestCase.py", line 216, in _connect
    raise self.failureException, str(value.response)
AssertionError: /contacts/41.json
HTTP Response 401: Unauthorized
```

i use funkload to test my application web

this is a part of my code :

```
#generation nombre between 1 et 109
i = random.randint(1,109)
#read photo
nameimage = "im"
nameimage=nameimage+str(i).zfill(1)+'.jpg'
self.logd(nameimage)
filephoto=open(nameimage,'rb')
image_data=filephoto.read()
filephoto.close()


b64_text = base64.b64encode(image_data)


const_image = {}
const_image['id'] = i
const_image['first_name'] = 'guest'
const_image['last_name'] = 'guest'
const_image['playload'] = b64_text
data=json.dumps(const_image)

#self.logd(data)

self.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')

#next request


self.put(self.server_url+"/contacts/41.json",Data('application/json',data),description = "put photo")
```

Comment: How do you send it? Code please.

Comment: you can show it now , thank you

Comment: Probably, that is, 401, your user is not autherized. Probably your pythonic client does not store cookies to authorize on the server. Clear cookies on a browser and try to make a such request from a browser and you will see the result. Am I right?

Comment: I clear cookies on a browser and i try to make a request ( i excute the code ) nothing change , i have always this error : HTTP Response 401: Unauthorized 

you think my code is correct ? i use json to send a photo , 
the content of this adress sever is also json

Comment: So, do you make a request within your browser, not within your script?

Comment: excuse me , how i make a request within my browser?

Comment: You can try to upload a photo by a standart way - by submitting a form with a 'file' field.

Comment: yes i upload a photo by a standart way , but me i will make it by a python script and i have always the problem